# Calculating the CPU-utilization given a round-robin scheduler with 1 ms time quantum, CPU-bound and I/O-bound tasks, and a context-switch time penalty

Tags: io, scheduling, cpu-usage

Consider a system running ten I/O-bound tasks and one CPU-bound task. Assume that the I/O-bound
tasks issue an I/O operation once for every millisecond of CPU computing and that each I/O operation takes
10 milliseconds to complete. Also assume that the context-switching overhead is 0.1 millisecond and that all
processes are long-running tasks.

If we're using a round-robin scheduler, how do I calculate the CPU-utilization if we have a 1 millisecond time quantum?

---

I'll spoil already that I don't know how to calculate the CPU utilization. I've tried to reason about the executions and timings below to hopefully hop on the right track.

Let's say the CPU-bound task starts, then we'll have an execution that looks somewhat like this

```
[CPUB] -> [CS] -> [IO1] -> [CS] -> [IO2] -> ... -> [IO10] -> [CS] -> [CPUB]
1         0.1     1        0.1     1               1         0.1     1
```

The time it takes from the CPU-bound task completing once to the point it starts executing again is `1 ms for CPU-bound task` + `10 CS, each 0.1 ms` + `10 I/O-bound tasks, each 1 ms` = `1 + 10*0.1 + 10*1 = 12 ms`. Out of those 12 ms, 11 out of them are spent idling (during each CS and during each I/O-bound task execution, thread running task will be blocked waiting for IO and as such CPU will idle).

Is all of this correct? And how do I continue?